# Wordpress custom taxonomy category filter, default value to get all categories

Tags: wordpress

I am trying create filter with AJAX which filter different taxonomy categories. For each taxonomy is filter listbox.
Filter is working if all listbox are chosen, but i need find way how filter categories if some of filter are not selected. How can query categories with empty value ? I have 4 listboxes, code is shortened.

Code:

```
$komanda = $_POST['komanda'];
$pretinieks = $_POST['pretinieks'];

if ($komanda == 0){ $komanda = '?'; }
if ($pretinieks == 0){ $pretinieks = '?'; }

$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'speles',
    'posts_per_page' => 99,
    'post_status' => array('publish'),
    'tax_query' => array(
                        'relation' => 'AND',
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'komandas',
                            'field'    => 'term_id',
                            'terms'    => $komanda,
                        ),
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'pretinieki',
                            'field'    => 'term_id',
                            'terms'    => $pretinieks,
                        ),
                    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution.

```
$komanda = $_POST['komanda'];
$pretinieks = $_POST['pretinieks'];

if ($komanda == 0){ 
    $terms = get_terms( 'komandas', 'orderby=count&hide_empty=1' );
    $komanda = array();
    $komanda = wp_list_pluck($terms, 'term_id');
}
if ($pretinieks == 0){ 
    $terms = get_terms( 'pretinieki', 'orderby=count&hide_empty=1' );
    $pretinieks = array();
    $pretinieks = wp_list_pluck($terms, 'term_id');
}

$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'speles',
    'posts_per_page' => 99,
    'post_status' => array('publish'),
    'tax_query' => array(
                        'relation' => 'AND',
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'komandas',
                            'field'    => 'term_id',
                            'terms'    => $komanda,
                        ),
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'pretinieki',
                            'field'    => 'term_id',
                            'terms'    => $pretinieks,
                        ),
                    )
);
```